# how to get index of a node in ListRewrite of Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am using Eclipse JDT to modify the AST of a source code. I want to modify a `MethodDeclaration` node. For that, I visited that using `ASTVisitor` and made changes. Now I removed the past node and am trying to add the new one at the same place using `ListRewrite.insertAt()` method. For that I want to get the index of the node before removing it. How can I get the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call `ListRewrite.replace()` instead of first removing then adding?

If that doesn't serve your purpose for some reason, try `listRewrite.getOriginalList().indexOf(oldNode)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty statement as a place holder and first replace this node with empty statement. Then make changes to your node. Then replace the empty statement with your node. This looks like a hack but works.